# Laminate separating from cabinet doors

Tags: laminate

I purchased a house with laminate cabinet doors, and later noticed that the laminate is not fully adhered.
It's kind of hard to tell from a picture but you can see the way it bulges out and catches the light in the top left corner.
[image]
The outer edges seem to be fine, but in the middle around where the design is it begins to separate.
I looked around but the only solutions I see are if it is peeling on the edges.
Would the whole coating need to be removed and glued or is there any easier way?

Comment: Any chance water/moisture getting into the door?

Comment: Is it just the one door?

Comment: I don't think there's any moisture getting to it.  
There are a few doors doing the same thing near the stove.

Comment: Thanks all. Seems like just ignoring it may be the best way to go and hope the next buyer doesn't notice like me.

Comment: If you ever get to the point that you need to replace them all, you'll find custom door providers online that can be very reasonable, price-wise.

Comment: are you certain  that the door is not shaped like that from the factory?

Comment: When you go to sell it, you're going to reface those BS-Home-Depot-Special cabinets in IKEA crap for 2k, or take a 10k hit on the sale price. Sooner than later? Get the metal faced ones that cost a saw blade every time you do it. Those seem to last pretty good even for tenets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's **not** swelling from moisture, and there's a "bubble" between the laminate surface and the core material, you can (roughly in order of difficulty):

- learn to ignore it.
- replace the whole door.
- Find someone with a vacuum-bag press and see if glue could be injected, and then have the thing placed in the vacuum bag to suck the surface flat until the glue cures. I believe this type of thing is typically made by a similar method, though it may involve some difficult to arrange outside of a factory "vacuum and heat" process.
- As above, but use a board the size of the middle of the door to press it with weights. If it's ONLY the middle that's peeling, that might work. Or it might encourage the "molding" sections around it to start peeling.
- Attempt to remove and replace the surface, as you mention. I have doubts about this producing a result that looks better than learning to ignore it, to be honest. It's not a DIY-friendly "finish."

If it's solid in the middle and has gotten wet at some point, causing the inside MDF to swell:

- replace the whole door.

Answer (score 1):

If the edges are adhering well and the bulge is only near the center, there is not a way to repair the door. ( Other than removing the laminate and reglueing a new panel.)

The idea of removing the old laminate and re attaching it is about impossible.
Having a piece of matching laminate that is larger than the door, so it can be trimmed is probably not likely. Additionally you probably don't have a router with a laminate trimming bit or a laminate trimmer.

The only reasonable way to correct your issue is to have a new door made. Try taking the door off and taking it to a custom cabinet maker.  They make doors like that every day.  You may have to buy a whole sheet of laminate ( 4' x8')
However the cost is much more reasonable than new cabinets.